# Display Sharepoint Promoted Links in rows and columns based on webpart title

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

I had few sharepoint promoted lists and I am displaying all the promoted lists in one webpart,All the promoted lists are having 2-3 promoted links. 
    But one of the promoted list is holding 5-6 links.I tried below css to make effect for particualr promoted list in webpart and found no luck.Can any one help me in solving this

.ms-WPTitle A:SMART,.ms-promlink-body {
      width: 480px;
}

Answer (score 0):

try use this:

```
.ms-promlink-body{position: static;width: inherit;height: inherit;}
.ms-promlink-header{display:none}
```

In my SharePoint 2013 I have successfully with this code.

reggards,

Comment: Thanks for your blaze response.As I said I am trying to implement by using webpart title.Below is the code implemented as per your gudiance ,but found no result

.ms-promlink-body{position: static;width: inherit;height: inherit;title:"LIBRARY"}

Comment: You have tried to insert this code in "edit page" > "edit web part" > "insert code"?

Comment: Used Webpart and added the promoted list in it.And implemented Script Editor to insert the code.